# Building range searches in Rails 4 and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**I have looked for the past few days on how to implement this correctly. have attempted several tutorials but none of them have seem to worked for me. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.**

What I need to do is allow users to do a search through the Profiles on my site, and they should be allowed to do this with ranges. For example I collect height and weight information, and a user should be able to search for someone between the weight of 140-150 lbs.

It seems like this should be a simple solution but I can not seem to find a good example or tutorial that shows me how to do this.

This is my model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :get_name
  after_create :get_city

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      attribs = columns.map(&:name)

      query = self.all

      (search.keys & attribs).each do |search_field|
        search_value = search[search_field]
        unless search_value.empty?
          query = query.where("#{search_field} ILIKE ?", "%#{search_value}%")
        end
      end
    else
      self.all
    end
  end

  def get_name
    self.user.update_name
    self.save
  end

  def get_city
    self.user.update_city
    self.save
  end
end
```

So I am able to actually search through my table, but can only currently search for one weight, I need to be able to search for a range. I am not sure if this is just a form_for thing I need to do or if I need to change the model itself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: assuming you have an attribute weight in your profile Profile.where(weight: 140..150) does not do the trick? Otherwise I don't fully get your question, how do you want to built up the range from this search param?

Comment: I would use an in query and pass a range.  It looks almost indistinguishable from a normal where query.  Profile.where(weight: [val_1...val_2])

Comment: That's the thing @jethroo, I do have a Profile.weight, but my question goes more into how do I implement this in a rails form. Currently I have the form structured like this:

<%= select_tag( :weight, options_for_select([  "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143"} ) %>

How can I turn this into a range system where a user can input two different values and the search would process it correctly.

Comment: well the easiest is to offer two fields one for the start and one for the end from whom you can built your query accordingly. This also can be realized with some JavaScript like the Datapickers do: offering multiple fields in the view which are then submitted combined

Comment: Right, I got that far in one tutorial, I guess my situation is that I do not understand how the flow of it should work. Do I still need to change the way my Profile Model search looks?

Comment: is your weight column contains only one value? can you tell us the datatype of a column.

Comment: its better if you post some data with dumy values

Comment: Yes currently, each Profile has a weight value. And each object can only have one weight.

Answer (score 1):

To send the weight as an array, you can have two fields in the form, like @jethroo said, and in the model, you could do something like this:

```
Profile.where(weight: Range.new(*params[:weight]))
```

`params[:weight]` is the array, like `["123", "140"]`

This will create an `SQL BETWEEN`, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profiles.weight BETWEEN 123 AND  140
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way that would work with the models I already had in place.

I ended up building a query and passed in specific query params, using a method on the Profile method first that checked different validations in the form, and based on the information, I would pass the search query into the Profiles model.

Hope that makes sense.